Spark executor does not see aws credentials env vars
I have a cluster made of 2 nodes (kubernetes pods), a YARN resource manager and a YARN node manager
Both pods have environment variables containing credentials to access a specific bucket in my AWS account, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
I then submit a spark application
This initially goes well, in s3 i see for example the Spark application's .inprogress files:


I also see the staging files directory:

Which is empty as i d not preserve those files.
So there is an initial, successfull, setup interaction between Spark and s3, the problem comes when the Spark application starts reading the data from the bucket, at least i think so.
The application fails with a message reporting that, although it uses an EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider in the providers chains, it cant find those variables:
Uncaught exception: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: BUCKET_NAME: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth.NoAuthWithAWSException: No AWS Credentials provided by SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider : com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: Unauthorized (Service: null; Status Code: 401; Error Code: null; Request ID: null)


I have fixed this by adding the keys in the configuration:
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.access.key: foo
spark.hadoop.fs.s3a.secret.key: bar

But i dont want this, i dont want to put my keys into Git as this is an application that is deployed via a statefulset within Kubernetes.
So i need to understand 2 things:
1- Why is Spark only 'partially' able to see and use the credentials stored in environment variables?
2- How can i let Spark executor pick those environment variables in the later stage (reading)? and connect to s3?
Thanks!
UPDATE
Even when i use EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider explicitly it wont work, the spark executor will fail , this time with a clear message that it cant find the env vars:
Uncaught exception: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: THE_BUCKET: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth.NoAuthWithAWSException: No AWS Credentials provided by EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider : com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY))
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AUtils.translateException(S3AUtils.java:187)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.once(Invoker.java:111)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.lambda$retry$3(Invoker.java:265)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retryUntranslated(Invoker.java:322)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retry(Invoker.java:261)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.Invoker.retry(Invoker.java:236)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.S3AFileSystem.verifyBucketExists(S3AFileSystem.java:391)

UPDATE2
I think i see what happens, Spark apps run on the same node as yarn node managers but in a different container, thats why it does not detect the env vars in the yarn-nm container, indeed when i manually set the env vars in Spark containers it works:
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: foo
spark.yarn.executorEnv.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: foo
spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: bar    
spark.yarn.executorEnv.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: bar

The question now is, how can i set those variables values by picking them from a secret installed in the same namespace/cluster?
